# How do I show two figures(plots) in a single window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

fig and fig1 give two different plots. Two different windows pop up. I want to show these two plots in a single window, may be separated by a line in the middle. How can I do that?

```
packing_options = get_packing_options(min_w, max_w, min_l, max_l, rect_list, step_size = 1, \

result_list = []
for opt in packing_options:
    step_w = float(get_max(opt.sheets))
    tmp_sheets = trim_sheets(opt.sheets, max(min_w,step_w), min_l)
    tmp_l = float(get_max(tmp_sheets,False))
    tmp_result_list = []
    tmp_w = step_w
    while area/tmp_w >= tmp_l:
        tmp_sheet = Sheet(tmp_w, area/tmp_w)
        tmp_result_list.append(find_best_packing_GA(tmp_sheet, sheets_to_rect_list(tmp_sheets), \
                                                    Pm = 0, rotate_prob = 0, flex = True, only_vertical = True))
        tmp_w = tmp_w + step_w
    result_list.append(best_individual(tmp_result_list)[0])

best, avg_fit, best_index = best_individual(result_list)


fig = packing_options[best_index].plot_sheets()

dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
dataPlot.draw()
dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

fig1 = best.plot_sheets()

dataPlot1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master = window)
dataPlot1.draw()
dataPlot1.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
```

This is the picture of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0meBZ.jpg

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: if you use the same `window` in `master=window` then it should be in one window. I hope you don't create two `Tk()` and don't use two `mainloop()`

Comment: @furas I used only one tk() and mainloop(). I have updated the question.

Comment: this code seems OK. You may have to show full code so we could run it.